# Found hardwood floors underneath carpet, but also maybe some MDF mixed in? Can I replace it? Picture inside

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

[image][image][image]So I found out my entire upstairs has hardwood floors. I pulled up the vents in each room. One room has what appears to be MDF board that is level with a section of the hardwood floor. See [image: attached photo]

It's very possible as I pull up more of the carpet I will find other areas with sections of MDF. It's likely some of the boards were damaged and they pulled em out to level out the surface before installing carpet over it right? Is it reasonable to think I could cut this MDF out and install new hardwood over it? I will then sand and finish it. It's 100% ok if the new hardwood "patches" don't end up looking the same as the old ones when all said and done.

Edit: New picture attached to show board thickness
[image]
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could repair the hard wood. Check out some more information on line so you understand how hardwood T&G is put down, I helped a friend that messed up quite a few boards to do a repair under a window that had leaked because he did not understand how the toe nailing worked. If the missing area is on the ends of the planks it is much tougher to repair compared to several length wise boards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ed Beal! A follow up question - is there a way to tell if the floors CAN be refinished? I'm adding a picture to the original post to show the thickness. I've been googling this and perhaps I'm not finding the right combination of words

Comment: As far as refinishing if it is a solid wood T&G floor I have always just rented a drum sander and sanded the floors I have never checked the thickness when it is real wood. Looking at the photo you will have plenty of thickness (you really don't take that much off).

Comment: I showed some of the pictures around here at work and there is some contention over whether it is real hard wood or not. I'm researching now to figure that out and then I'll go from there. Thanks again Ed.

Comment: Take a knife and clean up the edge it is fuzzy in the photo, if you see wood grain not something that looks like the underlayment and there is no vinyl or ? Covering on top of the boards it is probably real wood.

Comment: k I added 3 more pics. Once I got more pics and showed them to people, they agreed it was real hardwood. probably oak. I've attached them.

Comment: Real T&G , end of planks look to be real wood with the first picture I would say oak.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help Ed. Some more good news: Those white boards are actually the hardwood floors. What appears to have happened is that when they remodeled and decided to cover the hardwood floors with carpet, they spray painted the walls white and in the process, covered up some of the planks near the wall with white paint. I should be able to sand it out! I've attached one more picture that shows a room with all the carpet pulled up!

Comment: Hey Ed, a few more things since I've been reading about this

1. There's disagreement about what kind of sander to use. I'm thinking drum would be the way to go even though it's not as "newbie friendly." Do you have a strong disagreement with this?

Comment: 2. The internet also has disagreement on whether or not to pull the trim off. Do you have any opinions on this? If I pull the trim off, my understanding is that I might jack up the wall and end up having to replace sections of wall that could accidentally get torn off. Still trying to quantify how common such a scenario is or what I need to do to best ensure that doesn't happen

Comment: 3. How many coats do you suggest? I heard some people saying they did like 240 grit and up to 6 thin coats.

Comment: I like to remove the baseboards so I can get closer to the walls. With hard wood once finished the base boards will need to be moved down, they were probably moved up for the carpet. As far as How many coats it depends on the finish wanted, for floors 6 would be well beyond what I have ever seen both for remodel and new.

Comment: And are you a fan of the drum sander or the orbital style?

Comment: I have used drum Sanders for the majority of the refinish work, for DIY folks I recommend a finer grit paper because some folks go two corse and have a tough time controlling the amount taken off. I start as close to the wall working with the grain not across and then ~ 50% over lap until all the old finish is removed then use a fine grit finishing with smaller Sanders close to the wall. I can usually get within 1/2" without damaging the wall on the length wise runs and about 1-1/2 inches on the ends if I do go cross grain it is with a fine belt not a corse belt going cross grain.

Comment: Hey Ed this is kind of a different, but related question. I've been pulling the carpet up and getting the nails out, but about a half dozen are now headless. I watched several tutorials on how to get them out, but one of them broke and is now flush with the floor. The internet says to use a nail setter to punch the hole in and then fill it up. I bought a cheap set and tried that, but the nail would not budge at ALL. I hit the nail setter as hard as I could. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a tough one I habe had the same happen on Victorians that had oak framing and oak flooring. I have also had times where a nail set would not work in these cases I just used the sander and made sure it did not rip the belt, when all was done yes there were some nails that were sanded flush, I used a paint pen to knock the shine off and stained or varnished right over them it worked great. I have a contractor buddy that says the paint pen is not necessary but to me this keeps a bright shiny spot covered so it is hard to find even though I know it is there.

Comment: I found that holding the pin setter with some grips then taking a pretty big swing at it did the trick! I guess I was too afraid to swing hard at it with my hand holding the pin setter haha. Trim is off now on first and second room. Working on the third room.

Comment: Hey Ed. Things are coming along well with the floor prep stage. I will be sanding this weekend. I had a question about woodfiller. Do you only use woodfiller for holes or do you spread woodfiller with a trowel across the entire floor after the first sanding? I'm starting at 36 grit by the way then moving up to 60. I'm planning on finishing with 80 grit.

Comment: I usually rough sand first then fill and finish sand, I use a putty knife and work all the air voids out, use caution not to over fill or the sander might rip the filler out and you have to refill and wait, make sure to clean the areas to be filled no dust so the filler can attach to the wood.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Do you have a recommendation on finishing product? After reading a few articles I decided not to stain the floors. I was thinking of choosing Bona, but I am struggling to understand the "correct" procedure. Some people say you should put poly down first then the finishing product. Other people say poly, finish, poly. Then there's the issue of how many coats to use.  Also, within the Bona line,there's the "dri fast" "bona mega" "bona traffic hd" etc and obviously huge price differences between. Do you simply get what you pay for when it comes to choosing a finish?

Comment: I think you get what you pay for for the most part, if I want to stain I do that first then after that is dry I use poly, I prefer the solvent based poly as I have had the best results with several brands that were solvent based and quick dry time. For me I find 2 works but a 3rd coat really makes it look better beyond 3 is not usually necessary.

Comment: Hey Ed! I added a new picture. I've gotten the main sanding bit done now. I'm not gonna lie to you, for a office worker like me, that was VERY HARD WORK lol. I've gained an appreciation for people that do this for a living and you have my utmost respect. Anyways, I have a few weeks before staining and I would like to ask, what is the best way to remove edger swirls and imperfections created by the fact that I am an amateur? Should I buy one of those random orbital sanders?

Comment: A dual action sander will help remove the swirls, I find it takes longer with a finer paper but helps to remove swirls, make sure to work wider so you don't end up with low spots.or to say it differently make sure to blend the edge work to the center. The photo of the work so far looks good.

Comment: Hey Ed! I'm all finished. I've attached a few pictures. Definitely made some mistakes that I can see right away haha, but everyone that's come over to look has been really impressed. Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: The photo looks great, having a few doovers is part of learning but you have done a nice job and can say I did this. It is awesome to have a nice photo th show the results, others should up vote this for that reason.